# Recurrence relation of Beta function

Tags: calculus

Can we use this relationship only $B(x,y)=B(x,y+1)+B(x+1,y)$ to find the following relationship:

$$B(x+1,y)=B(x,y)\frac{x}{x+y}$$

Here $B(x,y)$ denotes the beta function.

Comment: You need take out a $x$ or $y$ from beta, and this relation doesn't help alone.

Comment: Please see my edit

Answer (score 1):

Use these identities:
$$B(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}\\
\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$$
and write your assumption as:
$$\begin{align}
B(x+1,y)&=-B(x,y+1)+B(x,y)\\
&=-\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y+1)}{\Gamma(x+y+1)}+B(x,y)\\
&=-\frac{y}{x+y}\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}+B(x,y)\\
&=B(x,y)\left(1-\frac{y}{x+y}\right)\end{align}$$
And if you don't want to use Gamma function, then try integration by parts. Beta function is defined by
$$B(x,y)=\int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}dt$$
Therefore
$$\begin{align}B(x,y+1)&=\int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y}dt\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac 1x(1-t)^{y}dt^x\\
&=0-\int_0^1 \frac 1x t^x d(1-t)^{y}\\
&=\int_0^1\frac yx t^x(1-t)^{y-1}dt=\frac yx B(x+1,y)\end{align}$$
Now put the above relationship into your assumption:
$$B(x,y)=B(x,y+1)+B(x+1,y)=(1+\frac yx)B(x+1,y)$$

Comment: The OP wants to prove with that property $B(x,y)=B(x,y+1)+B(x+1,y)$ only.

Comment: @MyGlasses I think the OP is able to speak for himself.

Comment: Sorry, I will vote another your post. But solution with Gamma function is simple, I mean $$B(x+1,y)=\dfrac{\Gamma(x+1)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y+1)}=\dfrac{x\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{(x+y)\Gamma(x+y)}=B(x,y)\frac{x}{x+y}$$

Comment: @MyGlasses I am not making this personal. But I think your interpretation of the question is meaningless. No hard feelings

Comment: Actually i want to calculate value of beta function without using gamma function. Is it possible?

Comment: @MyGlasses Turned out you were right

Comment: Even i don't want to use integration by parts to solve this. Now how will you find out this recurrence relation?

Comment: @pooja You should edit your question and tell what exactly do you want to use? The **definition** of beta function is all we have. It would be funny if you wanted to avoid even using that definition.

Comment: ok, I make it clear, as you know  integration by parts is not possible with respect to arbitrary measure. So if suppose, this relation  B(x,y)=B(x,y+1)+B(x+1,y)  holds with respect to arbitrary measure then how will you find recurrence relation of beta function.